# What is the difference between running docker image in and outside of vagrant

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Can anyone explain what is the difference of using docker images inside vagrant and outside of vagrant?

And how to deploy chaincode to the network that is running in docker containers outside of vagrant?

Now I have a network of 4 peers outside of vagrant, I'm trying to deploy a chaincode from github:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID": {
      "path": "https://github.com/aybek/test_ibm_chaincode"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
      "function": "init"
    },
    "metadata": [97, 115, 115, 105, 103, 110, 101, 114],
    "secureContext": "admin"
  },
  "id": 0
}
```

**Output:**

> Error when deploying chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code Getting chaincode took too long

Comment: Your question in your title is far too broad and then seems unrelated to the content of your question. Could you refine this?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to run the docker containers outside of vagrant.  There is a good example of how to run the docker containers and install/instantiate chaincode in the Fabric v1.0 documentation:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html